# Why isn't my Javascript script tag working?

Tags: javascript, django

My script tags in django are not working although my css is.

I've included `MEDIA_URL` and `STATIC_URL` in my base `urls.py` like so:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Only the script tags with the attributes `integrity` and `crossorigin` are working(external bootstrap cdn and jquery). But other scripts i.e. local scripts(javascript in the same file like I'll show below) and script tag with external source links (like `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>`) are not working.
The JavaScript code which is not working is:

```
<button id="togglebtn" class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 100%;">
         Checkout with a credit card
       </button>    //onClick didn't work
<script type="text/javascript">
 function toggleDisplay() {
      var x = document.getElementById("collapseStripe");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  document.getElementById("togglebtn").addEventListener("click", toggleDisplay);
</script>
```

I've added CSP in my settings.py file:

```
CSP_STYLE_SRC = ("'self'", 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/', ' https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css ',)
CSP_FONT_SRC = ("'self'",  'https://use.fontawesome.com/', )
CSP_IMG_SRC = ("'self'",  'https://js.stripe.com',)
CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS = ("'self'", 'frame-ancestors', 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/', 'https://js.stripe.com',)
CSP_SCRIPT_SRC = ("'self'", 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/', 'https://code.jquery.com/', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/',
                  'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/', 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/', 'https://js.stripe.com',
                  )
```

I don't know if this is a hindrance to the scripts.

Comment: Are you getting any (network/console) error?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a problem description. Please describe what is happening and what you think should happen instead.

Comment: @thebjorn doesn't work means when I click on the button with id `togglebtn` , the element with id `collapseStripe` doesn't show on and off.. Also the other external js files don't seem to be working

Comment: @art06 No, just the javascript isn't doing its thing..and the script with external links(crossorigin) don't seem to work..

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in your browser (in the `toggleDisplay()` function) -- does it find "collapseStripe"?

Comment: hey @thebjorn ,I just edited the question to add my settings. I tried to add csp but I doubt I've not written them the correct way.Please do check the edits.And I did tried to `console.log` to check if it's reaching the id `collapseStripe`,but it's not logging it instead showing `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource`. I can believe if it can't load crossorigins but why is it not loading the local script?